# Read out the expectations from a mock object

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

For google mock, and C++ specifically, is it possible to somehow read out the expectations set on a mock object and the status of them?

For example, is it possible to ask the mock object if it has any unfulfilled expectations at this point?

Reading out this information should not pass or fail the test, so `VerifyAndClearExpectations` is not what i'm looking for as it both determines the test result and changes the mock object.

Comment: The general philosophy is that you shouldn't need to know this, nor care about it.  What are you really trying to achieve that makes you think that you need to know or care about this?

Comment: @legalize I'm in a situation where code runs asynchronously. I want to wait until all expectations have been met, and continue directly after that (of for some longish interval if they don't get met). Having such a feature would allow me to speed up tests which run in different environments.

Comment: @JörnSchellhaas Testing code with concurrent (or asynchronous) operations can be tricky, but the general recommendation is to have the test case orchestrate the concurrency/asynchrony appropriately in order to handle the situation.  The mock framework shouldn't enter into it IMO.

Comment: I understand that, @legalize. Yet, I'd love having a subscribe mechanism on when the expectations are met. Because tests should be fast. Fortunately, our mocks are simple enough to just manually implement sychronization. It's a bit cluttered, however.

Comment: @JörnSchellhaas Sounds like it would be worth it's own question to get more eyeballs on it and see if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, google mock provides no such functionality.